# Is DATE_RFC3339 PHP constant strictly equal to DATE_W3C

Tags: php, html, datetime, datetime-format

I'm using HTML5 and datetime input type. To set its value, I use a PHP DateTime object which iIformat to match with W3C Specification (actually by using DATE_RFC3339).
I was wondering if DATE_RFC3339 was strictly equal to DATE_W3C as W3C say [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.datetime).

To finish, I was wondering if `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'` was the good format for `<input type="datetime-local" />` as we can use the following format (with millisceonds) : `1985-04-12T23:20:50.52`.

Thanks in advance and please forgive my bad english.

Comment: Yes, DATE_RFC3339 and DATE_W3C are the exact same. http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are identical.

From php.net documentation:

```
const string RFC3339 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP";
const string W3C = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Thanks, What about datetime-local format, is there any prefedined constant?

Comment: I hit a snag with DATE_RFC3339, PHP and <input type="datetime-local"/>
If you're trying to format a DateTime object to use as the pre-defined input value, for some reason :
$date->format(DATE_RFC3339) won't work, probably because it includes the offset e.g.
value="2015-05-12T09:15:00+02:00"
After some experimenting, I found that this works :
value=\"" . $date->format("Y-m-d\TH:i") . "\"
As per the example above, you need to escape the "\T" in the format string. It works for seconds too :
value=\"" . $date->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s") . "\"